# Followers query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

People can upload photos on my website. They can also follow people. To create feed I need to create query which selects all of my followers and order them by date of upload.
I have 2 tables:

`follows`:

```
follower|followed
 4      | 6
 6      | 4
```

This is example - user id 6 is following user id 4 and 4 is following 6.

My other table is `images`:

```
id          |uploader|time               |...more data...
JFZFXVCusz2p| 4      |2014-02-21 21:58:43|
pclz56eKqTbZ| 6      |2014-02-18 23:53:52|
```

Can you help me out with this query. I need to select all images of the users followed by id 4 (for example) and order them by upload date.

Comment: Something like `SELECT followed, time FROM follows JOIN images ON follows.followed = images.time;` Sorry, I did not test the query and I am asleep :) Hope I understood what do you need. Btw. read about RIGHT/LEFT/INNER/OUTER JOIN. Also do not forget and add indexes to followed and time.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM images WHERE uploader IN (SELECT followed FROM follows WHERE follower = USER_ID) ORDER BY time DESC`?

Comment: Even better answer from @Sean. Actually `IN` is faster than `JOIN` on `DISTINCT`

Comment: @Sean Thanks, it works. Can you make that as an answer so I could select it as correct ?

Comment: @WigglerJtag Thanks, but I will use Sean's query since it's faster. If you formulate this as an answer I will give it thumb up, because it's still working solution.

Comment: Np. Sure, use the best option :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a subquery `SELECT` and `IN`

```
SELECT * 
FROM images 
WHERE uploader IN (
          SELECT followed 
          FROM follows 
          WHERE follower = USER_ID)
ORDER BY time DESC
```